# IBM i (AS400) to SQL Server table join syntax

Tags: sql-server, join, ibm-midrange

I am using Excel Connection to query customer contracts from DB2 for IBM i (AS400) through SQL Server connection and trying to join a SQL Server table to determine contract expiration date and sales team responsibility.

The AS400 query operates but I continue to receive an error on joining the SQL Server table `ACCOUNT.dbo.CUSTOMER` but can't find reference to alternate syntax on the join.

```
[select  *
from openquery(
bpcsrpt_new,'
select s.SCID, s.SVER, s.CONTEXP, a.ACCTNAME, a.SALESTEAM

from AS400table1.contract c, AS400table1.subcontract s, ACCOUNT.dbo.CUSTOMER a

where c.cid=''Active''
and c.cid=s.scid
and c.cver=s.sver
and c.cid=a.acid')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not going to work.  When you use openquery, the statement gets sent to the remote machine.  Obviously, ACCOUNT.dbo.CUSTOMER is not on the remote IBM i (aka AS400) machine.

You could use 4 part naming in the query directly

```
select s.SCID, s.SVER, s.CONTEXP, a.ACCTNAME, a.SALESTEAM
from IBMILNKNAM.IBMIDBNAM.IBMILIBNAM.contract c
     , IBMILNKNAM.IBMIDBNAM.IBMILIBNAM.subcontract s
     , ACCOUNT.dbo.CUSTOMER a
where c.cid='Active'
and c.cid=s.scid
and c.cver=s.sver
and c.cid=a.acid
```

Note however, the SQL Server will pull back the complete contract and subcontract tables to do the join locally.

Openquery is a better option if you're only interested in a few rows of a large table on the IBM i.  If I recall correctly, something like so:  (not tested)

```
select  * 
from (select * from Openquery(IBMIKNKNAM, 'select s.SCID, s.SVER, s.CONTEXP 
                            from contract c
                                 join subcontract s 
                                       on c.cid=s.scid
                                       and c.cver=s.sver
                           where c.cid=''Active'')) as rmt
      join ACCOUNT.dbo.CUSTOMER a on a.acid = rmt.cid
```

Comment: Thank you Charles.  Your second option worked perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear...means my memory is not completely shot!  One more thing to add...Note that in the second example I'm using explicit joins, rather than the implicit joins in your example.  Best practice is to use explicit joins with the join criteria in `FROM` instead of implicit joins with join criteria in the `WHERE`